# Is it safe to store paint in a furnace room?

Tags: paint, safety, storage

I currently store my paint cans, mostly latex but a few oil-based stains, in my furnace room.

I'm not certain if latex paints are dangerous to keep near flame sources, but I'm fairly certain that oil-based products are.

However, I'm unsure as to where else I can store them.  My alternate locations are my garage or attic, but both are unheated and the northern Ohio winters will almost certainly freeze the paint.

Where can I safely store paint?  Are latex based products safe to store in a furnace room?

Answer (score 1):

If your paints will be in close proximity of the furnace I wouldn't do that.  If they are in the same room and the room has ventilation but away from furnace I would go there.

I wouldn't store anything like this in the attic for sure.  Unless your attic is somewhat finished and you go up there all the time I wouldn't.  You don't want cans spilling or issues in a place that could affect house and really in a place that you don't keep track of.  That is why I would throw them on shelves in the garage if the attic doesn't work.  If your garage is attached for the most part you shouldn't have many days in there below freezing and almost none that go below the paints freeze point.

Answer (score 1):

It is a violation of nearly all fire codes to store both flammable and combustible liquids near ignition sources, like your furnace. That would include any oil-based surficial finish (paint, stain, varnish, spray paints, etc.).

Although latex paints and their separated products are not classified as combustible or flammable, it may be a fire code violation to store them in a commercial furnace room if they impede safe movement within the enclosed space or if there are enough of them to impede furnace ventilation.

Comment: ok, so latex products can be stored in furnace room, thank you.  What about oil based products?  Where can they be stored?